# NULL not allowed for column "CREATION_DATE";

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to execute my save endpoint into postman and I am receiving this error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: NULL not allowed for column "CREATION_DATE"; SQL statement:
>   insert into tcustomer (authentication_uid, creation_date, customer_uid, default_payment_method_uid, guid, last_edit_date, pref_bill_address_uid, pref_ship_address_uid, status, storecode, type, user_id, uidpk) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-195]

This is the Json for insertion into postman:

```
{
 "userId":"pelzer.nyatt@yahoo.fr",
 "pref_bill_address_uid": "NULL", 
 "pref_ship_address_uid": "NULL",
 "creation_date": "2017-05-22T20:19:37.855",
 "last_edit_date": "2017-10-01T11:11:11.755",
 "guid": "5682ff69-e037-4d11-9db8-8d5ce7ad2285",
 "status": 1, 
 "authentication_uid": 6809573,
 "type": "CustomerExtImpl", 
 "storecode": "S_100",  
 "default_payment_method_uid": "NULL",
 "customer_uid":"NULL"
}
```

**This is my cutomer Entity class with the creation_date field**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tcustomer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence",sequenceName = "sequence_tcustomer", allocationSize = 100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
private Long uidpk;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable=false)
private String userId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "pref_bill_address_uid")
private CustomerAddress prefBillAddressUid;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "pref_ship_address_uid")
private CustomerAddress prefShipAddressUid;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = CustomerProfileValue.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_uid")
private CustomerProfileValue customerProfileValue;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = CustomerAddress.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_uid")
private List<CustomerAddress> customerAddress = new ArrayList<CustomerAddress>();

@Column(name = "default_payment_method_uid")
private Long defaultPaymentMethodUid;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "authentication_uid")
private CustomerAuthentication authenticationUid;

@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable=false)
private Date creationDate;

@Column(name = "last_edit_date", nullable=false)
private Date lastEditDate;

@Column(name = "guid", nullable=false)
private String guid;

@Column(name = "status", nullable=false)
private Long status;

@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "storecode", nullable=false)
private String storecode;

//getters and setters
```

I am open for providing more informations thks

Comment: How do you convert the date from Json to the Date in the entity?

Comment: I dont really  know if you are  talking about the CustomerMapper?  I dont have a specific way. Any idea for more udenstanding please

Comment: i have a  DateUtil classe witht both methods. <br/>`    public static Date parse(String dateToParse) throws ParseException <br/>   public static String format(Date dateToFormat)`

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check if the field has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json should follow the names of the variables in your entity.
So, instead of "creation_date" it should be "creationDate" (and you should change it for all your json).

When you add this:

```
@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable=false)
private Date creationDate;
```

Basically it means that there is a column in the database called "creation_date" that is not nullable and you are mapping to your code as "creationDate".

Comment: That's the wrong answer because Hibernate is transforming Camel case in _ so creationDate = creation_date

Comment: ok i Did it and the error into the Postman has changed to :   "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of  
 fr.kiabi.bekom.services.customer.domain.CustomerAddress: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('NULL');

Comment: When you are passing "NULL" on your json, you really mean that the values are a string written "NULL" on your databse or you want it to be null value on your database? If you want them to be null, just don't pass it on your json (the whole tag : value sentence).

Comment: i want the value to be null into databasse. so i dit it _"prefBillAddressUid": " ",  _ :   ** ERROR**  JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of fr.kiabi.bekom.services.customer.domain.CustomerAddress: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('');

Comment: @solo if you want null into database, don't add it to json at all. If you add "prefBillAddressUid": "", you are still adding an empty string. And the error you are getting it's because you are trying to pass a string into a List on your json.

Comment: Thing getting better i thing so @FerA  i did as you said   "prefBillAddressUid": null,     _error : JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of fr.kiabi.bekom.services.customer.domain.CustomerAuthentication: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (6809573);_

Comment: { "userId":"pelzer.nyatt@yahoo.fr", "creationDate": "2017-05-22T20:19:37.855", "lastEditDate": "2017-10-01T11:11:11.755", "guid": "5682ff69-e037-4d11-9db8-8d5ce7ad2285", "status": 1, "authenticationUid": 6809573, "type": "CustomerExtImpl", "storecode": "S_100", } The null values won't be passed on json

Comment: @FerA true when making insertion with Json you  should follow the names of the variables in your entity.  thk you